# list[-1] does not work properly

Tags: python, list

Problem 1:

```
li=[1,2,3,4,5]
li[-1]
-bash: li[-1]: command not found
```

Problem 2:

```
`str="中国人民”
print（str[-1]）
-bash:人`
```

Why am I always getting `str[-2]` instead of `str[-1]`? Do I need to change some system parameter?

Comment: The problem with your python is that it's bash...

Comment: are you running this with the python interpreter? or saving the files as .py files?

Comment: Do you have a Python REPL going?

Comment: Just a note, bash does have the same ability to index with negative numbers from the back of an array, using similar syntax: `${li[-1]}`